# Why compiler complain about this macro declaration

Tags: c, debugging, c-preprocessor

I write the following macro for debug convinience,

```
1 #ifndef DEF_H
2 #define DEF_H
3 #define DEBUG_MODE
4 #define DEBUG_INFO(message)     \
5         #ifdef DEBUG_MODE       \
6                 cout << message << endl; \
7         #endif                          \
8 #endif
```

but gcc complains as the following

```
def.h:4: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
def.h:1: error: unterminated #ifndef
```

What's wrong with this piece of code? Do I miss some important points here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot have `#ifdef`s inside a macro definition.  You need to turn it inside out:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
#define DEBUG_INFO(message) cout << (message) << endl
#else
#define DEBUG_INFO(message)
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you. So how can I achieve the goal using macro to control the debug switch. In the client end, I prefer to call just a single line like DEBUG_INFO("debug info")

Comment: +1. Also, there is a backslash after line 7, which causes the #endif in the last line to be part of line 4, and not match the #ifndef in the first line

Answer (score 3):

You can't embed a preprocessor directive in another preprocessor directive (the `#ifdef DEBUG_MODE` inside the definition of `DEBUG_INFO`).  Instead, do something like

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
# define DEBUG_INFO(message) cout << message << endl
#else
# define DEBUG_INFO(message) 0
#endif
```

(This is still not ideal; defensive macro coding suggests something like

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
# define DEBUG_INFO(message) do {cout << message << endl;} while (0)
#else
# define DEBUG_INFO(message) 0
#endif
```

Perhaps an `inline` function would work better.)

Comment: "You can't embed a preprocessor directive in another preprocessor directive ", this is not true for all cases, is it ? e.g. #if, #ifdef and #ifndef

Answer (score 0):

I geuss if you eat '\' at line 7, the piece of Code will work.