# Preprocessor fails due to - '#' is not followed by a macro parameter

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to simplify the declaration of an array, but ran into an issue with the preprocessors that I am using.  My initial code looks like the following:

```
#define REQ_ENTRY(parm_1, parm_2)    \
#if defined(parm_1)                  \
    { parm_1, parm_2 },              \
#endif

typedef struct {
    int parm1,
        parm2;
} MyTypedef_t;

static const MyTypedef_t MyList[] =
{
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_1, 1 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_2, 2 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_3, 3 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_4, 4 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_5, 5 )
};
```

The build fails, of course, with the error message of "error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter".  The reason for this is explained here ([Why compiler complain about this macro declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074520/why-compiler-complain-about-this-macro-declaration))

Basically, I am trying to avoid declaring the array as the follows, which does work:

```
static const MyTypedef_t MyList[] =
{
    #if defined (ID_1)
    { ID_1, 1 },
    #endif

    #if defined (ID_2)
    { ID_2, 2 },
    #endif

    #if defined (ID_3)
    { ID_3, 3 },
    #endif

    #if defined (ID_4)
    { ID_4, 4 },
    #endif

    #if defined (ID_5)
    { ID_5, 5 },
    #endif        
};
```

The list can be rather long and vary depending upon the build type of the project.  I have tried thinking of using x-macros, but I think I would have the same issue.  I am hoping someone might see a way of creating the preprocessor macros in such a way that I could achieve the original sugar syntax?  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can wrap `#ifdef` around a macro definition; you can't embed it inside one.  Also, you can't directly test whether an argument to a macro is a defined macro.  Unfortunately, the nay-saying is the easy part; it is not clear that there's a good way to avoid your original code.  That's what I've used in equivalent circumstances.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no nice clean solution. But there are solutions of varying ugliness.

If you don't mind including both the *id* and the *sequence* in the macro definition, it can be solved like this:

```
#define CONCAT2(x,y) x##y
#define CONCAT(x,y) CONCAT2(x,y)
#define REQ_ENTRY_YES(p1, p2) { p1 , p2 }
#define REQ_ENTRY_NO(p1) 
#define IS_PAIR_HELPER(a, b, c, ...) c
#define IS_PAIR(...) IS_PAIR_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__, YES, NO)
#define REQ_ENTRY(pair) CONCAT(REQ_ENTRY_, IS_PAIR(pair))(pair)

#define ID_1 78723649, 1
#define ID_3 2347602, 3

typedef struct {
    int parm1,
        parm2;
} MyTypedef_t;

static const MyTypedef_t MyList[] =
{
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_1 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_2 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_3 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_4 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_5 )
};
```

---

Run through gcc with `-std=c11 -Wall -E`, and showing only the `MyList` definition:

```
static const MyTypedef_t MyList[] =
{
    { 78723649 , 1 }

    { 2347602 , 3 }


};
```

---

You can do the same thing by using *any* second value in the `#define ID_x` macros, as long as there is one; the real parameters can be added to `REQ_ENTRY`. But it takes some extra juggling.

Answer (score 5):

It's a pity that the `defined` operator is available only in the context of `#if` and `#ifelse`, but not for macro expansions. As it stands, I agree with rici about the solutions of varying ugliness.

Here's a solution that requires that the defined values be surrounded by parentheses. You can then use the ID as regular value and you can also pass it to `DEF`, which expands to either 1 when the macro is in parentheses or 0 if not. (That's a trick I learned [here](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms).)

With the help of the `DEF` macro, you can create auxiliary macros that expand or ignore the given definition:

```
/* Auxiliary macros */

#define M_CHECK(...) M_CHECK_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define M_CHECK_(a, b, ...) b

#define M_IS_PAREN(x) M_CHECK(M_IS_PAREN_ x, 0)
#define M_IS_PAREN_(...) 1, 1

#define M_CONCAT(a, b) M_CONCAT_(a, b)
#define M_CONCAT_(a, b) a ## b

/* Conditional definition macros */

#define DEF(x) M_IS_PAREN(x)

#define DEF_IF_0(id, def)
#define DEF_IF_1(id, def) {id, def},

#define COND_DEF(x, y) M_CONCAT(DEF_IF_, DEF(x))(x, y)

/* Implementation */

#define ID_1 (27)
#define ID_3 (28)
#define ID_4 (29)

static const MyTypedef_t MyList[] = {
    COND_DEF(ID_1, 1)
    COND_DEF(ID_2, 2)
    COND_DEF(ID_3, 3)
    COND_DEF(ID_4, 4)
    COND_DEF(ID_5, 5)
};
```

This will produce:

```
static const MyTypedef_t MyList[] = {
    {(27), 1},

    {(28), 3},
    {(29), 4},

};
```

You can also use the `DEF` macro in code, which will be expanded to either 0 or 1:

```
printf("ID_1 is %s.\n", DEF(ID_1) ? "defined" : "undefined");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I was able to get without introducing redundancy:

```c
#define PREPROCESSOR_IF #if
#define PREPROCESSOR_ENDIF #endif
#define PREPROCESSOR_NEWLINE /*
*/

#define REQ_ENTRY(parm_1, parm_2)                         \
PREPROCESSOR_IF defined(parm_1)      PREPROCESSOR_NEWLINE \
    { parm_1, parm_2 },              PREPROCESSOR_NEWLINE \
PREPROCESSOR_ENDIF

typedef struct {
    int parm1,
        parm2;
} MyTypedef_t;

static const MyTypedef_t MyList[] =
{
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_1, 1 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_2, 2 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_3, 3 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_4, 4 )
    REQ_ENTRY( ID_5, 5 )
};
```

You need to run the preprocessor only once using `-E` and `-CC` and then compile the result of the first preprocessor pass, however it does not work due to (for example)

```c
#if defined (ID_1) /*
*/ { ID_1, 1 }, /*
*/ #endif
```

not being recognized as distinct lines for the preprocessor, since the comments are replaced by just one space.

I was able to come up with a solution using redundancy, but it is hardly better than what you proposed (writing out the whole statement each time):

```c
#define PREPROCESSOR_IF #if
#define PREPROCESSOR_ENDIF #endif
#define PREPROCESSOR_DEFINE #define
#define PREPROCESSOR_NEWLINE /*
*/

#define REQ_ENTRY_1(parm_1, parm_2) PREPROCESSOR_IF defined(parm_1)
#define REQ_ENTRY_2(parm_1, parm_2) { parm_1, parm_2 }, 
#define REQ_ENTRY_3(parm_1, parm_2) PREPROCESSOR_ENDIF

PREPROCESSOR_DEFINE ID_1 (27)
PREPROCESSOR_DEFINE ID_3 (28)
PREPROCESSOR_DEFINE ID_4 (29)

typedef struct {
    int parm1,
        parm2;
} MyTypedef_t;

static const MyTypedef_t MyList[] =
{
    REQ_ENTRY_1( ID_1, 1 )
    REQ_ENTRY_2( ID_1, 1 )
    REQ_ENTRY_3( ID_1, 1 )

    REQ_ENTRY_1( ID_2, 2 )
    REQ_ENTRY_2( ID_2, 2 )
    REQ_ENTRY_3( ID_2, 2 )

    REQ_ENTRY_1( ID_3, 3 )
    REQ_ENTRY_2( ID_3, 3 )
    REQ_ENTRY_3( ID_3, 3 )

    REQ_ENTRY_1( ID_4, 4 )
    REQ_ENTRY_2( ID_4, 4 )
    REQ_ENTRY_3( ID_4, 4 )

    REQ_ENTRY_1( ID_5, 5 )
    REQ_ENTRY_2( ID_5, 5 )
    REQ_ENTRY_3( ID_5, 5 )
};
```

This does compile as desired using the two-step compilation process described above.

Comment: I wanted to try this in my regular compilation process, unfortunately I get `error: stray '#' in program` `note: in expansion of macro 'PREPROCESSOR_IF'`