# Is it possible to define macro inside macro?

Tags: c, macros

I want to use macro parameter like this:

```
  #define D(cond,...) do{         \
    #if cond                      \
    #define YYY 1                 \
    #else                         \
    #define YYY 0                 \
  } while(0)
```

Is it possible?

**UPD**
Maybe when sources will be preprocessed twice: `gcc -E source.c | gcc -xc -` next will work:

```
#define D(cond,...) #define YYY cond&DEBUG
#if YYY
#define D(...) printf( __VA_ARGS__ )
#else
#define D(...)
#endif
```

Comment: No. *<space filler>*

Comment: Why do you think you need to?

Comment: I mean literally "No". And stop abusing macros, these considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: What are you attempting with it?

Comment: Think about it: the preprocessor can't possibly know what happens at runtime, so it is impossible to define a macro after the preprocessor is done.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Everything has its uses.

Comment: @machine_1 Sure. But the OP is clearly trying to *abuse* them (here and in his previous question).

Comment: @EugeneSh. I wouldn't call that an abuse, just a clever idea that shows the macro's limitations. What he asks is completely possible btw.

Comment: @ft_error Really? 4 answers claim it is not possible. Including yours

Comment: @EugeneSh. I meant possible in the way that what he wants to do is achieveable in other ways, and i think it his concept would be a nice addition to the C preprocessor, it would cause some sort of recursive preprocessor passing after himself and eventually an infinite loop of recursion of a macro defining its own definition, that would be awesome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preprocessor fails due to - '#' is not followed by a macro parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774678/preprocessor-fails-due-to-is-not-followed-by-a-macro-parameter)

Answer (score 7):

**This is not possible.** Read about the [GNU `cpp` preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) and the C11 standard (i.e. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), and check [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c). The [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) is (conceptually at least) run before the rest of the compiler (which gets the *preprocessed* form of your [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))). BTW, for a file `foo.c` you could use `gcc -C -E foo.c > foo.i` (using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) to get inside `foo.i` its preprocessed form, and you can inspect that `foo.i` -since it is a textual file- with a pager or an editor.

However, **a `.c`  file can be generated** (generating C code is a common practice, at least since the 1980s; for example with [yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc), [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [rpcgen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), [swig](http://swig.org/), ....; many large software projects use specialized generators of C or C++ code...). You might consider using some other tool, perhaps the [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) preprocessor (or [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html)) or some other program or script, to generate your C file (from something else). Look also into [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) (it might have goals similar to yours).

You may want to configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool for such purpose, e.g. edit your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) for [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).

Answer (score 7):

No, because [C 2011 [N1570] 6.10.3.4 3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.4p3) says, about macro replacement, “The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one,…”

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible.

During translation, all preprocessing directives (`#define`, `#include`, etc.) are executed *before* any macro expansion occurs, so if a macro expands into a preprocessing directive, it won't be interpreted as such - it will be interpreted as (invalid) source code.

Comment: If all preprocessing directives were executed before any macro expansion, `#if MyPreprocessorSymbol == 3` would not work. You have to expand the preprocessor symbol before evaluating the `#if`. You can even use preprocessor macros in a `#include` statement, per C 2011 [N1570] 6.10.2 4.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by others this is not possible but there is a work around:

```
int YYY;
/* global scope variables are sometimes considered bad practice... */
#define D(cond,...) do{         \
  if (cond) {                   \
  YYY = 1;                      \ 
  }                             \
  else {                        \
  YYY = 0;                      \
  }                             \
} while(0)
```

Use an optimizing flag (ex: `gcc/clang -O3`) and it will replace the dead code as if it was a macro. Obviously you may want to change the type of YYY but you seem to use it like a boolean.

Comment: Hi. I try your example, but it always generate `if(0){ ...` despite on first parameter to `D`: `D(1, "some string" )`. Also I find interesting trick: we can preprocess sources twice: `gcc -E source.c | gcc -xc -`

Comment: This is a really nice trick!

I edited my answer, i am sorry i did't understand you wanted to use cond as a literal, i thought it was a define condition...

Now this should work.

Comment: yes, it should be define condition. and when `cond` is 0 no code should be generated.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. The C preprocessor cannot know what is going to occur during runtime.

The preprocessor goes through the program before it is even compiled and replaces every macro defined with its assigned value.

Comment: This does not involve preprocessing after translation. The idea in the question is that the D macro would be expanded somewhere later in the source, and, after that expansion, the replacement text would then be rescanned for preprocessor directives. This would all occur during preprocessing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The interesting trick is to preprocess sources twice: `gcc -E source.c | gcc -xc -`

Comment: @EugenKonkov: That does not work on the first code sequence in the question because `\` followed by new-line is deleted during translation phase 2, before preprocessing, so the resulting `D` macro does not have new-line characters in its replacement text, so the expanded preprocessing directives are not on separate lines. It does not work on the first or the second code sequence because `#` is an operator in macro replacement (it stringifies) and must be followed by a macro parameter, so `#if` is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

This is some poor man's code generation, for when integrating another tool to the project is overkill.

Define a macro like this, expanding for your needs:

```
#define NESTED              /* Comment out instead of backslash new lines.
*/                          /*
*/  UNDEF   REPLACED        /*
*/                          /*
*/  IFDEF   CONDITION       /*
*/  DEFINE  REPLACED  1     /*
*/  ELSE                    /*
*/  DEFINE  REPLACED  0     /*
*/  ENDIF
```

Your version of `NESTED` can be a function-like macro, and `REPLACED` can have a more elaborated body.

Leave `CONDITION` and the directive named macros without a definition.

`DEFINE CONDITION` to control which value `NESTED` gets on compilation, similarly to normal `#ifdef` usage:

```
DEFINE  CONDITION
NESTED
int i = REPLACED;        //i == 1

UNDEF  CONDITION
NESTED
int z = REPLACED;        //z == 0
```

Source code that uses `NESTED` and the other macros  will not compile. To generate a `.c` or `.cpp` file that you can compile with your chosen options, do this:

```
gcc   -E -CC   source.c  -o temporary.c
gcc   -E                                                  \
   -DDEFINE=\#define  -DUNDEF=\#undef                     \
   -DIFDEF=\#ifdef    -DELSE=\#else    -DENDIF=\#endif    \
   temporary.c  -o usableFile.c

rm temporary.c     #remove the temporary file
```

`-E` means preprocess only, not compile. The first `gcc` command expands `NESTED` and all normally defined macros from the source. As `DEFINE`, `IFDEF`, etc. are not defined, they and their future arguments remain as literal text in the `temporary.c` file.

`-CC` makes the comments be preserved in the output file. After the preprocessor replaces `NESTED` by its body, `temporary.c` contains the directive macros in separate lines, with the comments. When the comments are removed on the next gcc command, the line breaks remain by the standard.

`#` is accepted in the body of a macro that takes no arguments. However, unlike macros, directives are not rescaned and executed on expansion, so you need another preprocessor pass to make nested defines work. All preprocessing related to the delayed defines needs to be delayed too, and made available to the preprocessor at once. Otherwise, directives and arguments needed in a later pass are consumed and removed from the code in a previous one.

The second `gcc` command replaces the `-D` macros by the delayed directives, making all of them available to the preprocessor starting on the next pass. The directives and their arguments are not rescaned in the same gcc command, and remain as literal text in `usableFile.c`.

When you compile `usableFile.c`, the preprocessor executes the delayed directives.